# Does an invertible $(n \times n)$-matrix over $R$ induce an $R$-algebra Automorphism of a given free $R$-algebra $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I am a bit puzzled right now. Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$. Assume we have an $R$-algebra $A$ free of rank $n$ with two bases $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ and $b_1,\ldots,b_n$. Let $M = (m_{i,j})_{i,j} \in R^{n \times n}$ be an invertible matrix over $R$. Then $M$ describes an $R$-**module** automorphism $\phi$ of $A$ via $\phi(a_i) = \sum_{j=1}^n m_{i,j} b_j$.

But does $M$ also provide an $R$-**algebra** automorphism? What happens with the relations $a_ia_j = \sum_{\ell=1}^n \mu_{i,j,\ell} a_\ell$? If the induced $\phi$ is not $R$-multiplicative, what extra condition does the matrix have to satisfy? I guess, it need in some sense relate the relations of both bases.

I am grateful for any kind of help! I am pretty sure that I am stupid right now$\ldots$

Comment: What is $R$? Presumably it's a ring, but you should say so explicitly. Is $R$ commutative?

Comment: @BenGrossmann Yes, $R$ is a commutative ring with $1$.

Comment: $\phi$ is not necessarily an automorphism, even if $R$ is a field. For instance, consider $\Bbb C \cong \Bbb R^2$ as an $\Bbb R$-algebra. If we take $M = 2I$, then we have $\phi(x) \phi(y) = 4xy$, but $\phi(xy) = 2xy$.

Comment: Also, we can see that $M$ only defines an algebra automorphism in the rank-$1$ case if $M  = 1$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann That is a good example. What about the converse? So what does the matrix of an $R$-algebra automorphism satisfy?

Comment: If I knew, I'd have written an answer. At the very least, though, we must have $\det m_{\phi(a)} = \det m_a$, where $m_a:x \mapsto ax$.

Comment: The term "free algebra" does not mean "algebra whose underlying module is a free module", but instead is defined analogously to a free module (or free group or free monoid, etc.), which is where confusion arises.